# Are there local coordinates for Schwarzchild spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, relative-motion

In the Schwarzchild metric, $t$ is the time on the clock of an observer at infinity, and $r$ is the related to the area of a sphere by $A=4\pi r^2$. Are there more physical coordinates one could use, where $t$ is the time on the clock of an observer at finite $r$, and $r$ refers to distances this observer could actually measure with a meter stick? I know the metric will depend on the motion of the observer, but perhaps there are some "preferred frames" that are more relevant than others?

Comment: The metric for a uniformly accelerated observer is the Rindler metric, and this has already been discussed to death on this site, [not least by me](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=rindler%20user%3a1325). For time dependent acceleration the metric will be time dependent but will look locally like the Rindler metric. Also see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146280/how-to-describe-arbitrary-accelerations-in-special-relativity). Can you clarify exactly what it is you are asking that isn't covered by previous questions?

Comment: Now you've updated the question isn't it just asking for the transformation between the accelerated and non-accelerated coordinates? If so that's just the [relativistic rocket equations](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) which have also been [discussed to death on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=relativistic%20rocket).

Comment: It now looks as if you're asking about the local geometry for [shell observers](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/coursewikis/GGR/book/ggr/schwobs)

Comment: Actually I don't get it - in the shell article you just sent me, the metric is $-\sigma_t^2 + \sigma_r^2 + ...$. Doesn't that mean that the metric is flat? I know it's locally flat, but here it looks totally flat.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer The quantities $\sigma_\mu$ are one-forms, but they are not _exact_ one-forms. In other words, they don't necessarily satisfy $d\sigma_\mu=0$, like they would if $\sigma_\mu=dx_\mu$. So a metric of the form $-\sigma_t^2+\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2+\sigma_z^2$ is not necessarily flat. Case in point: the Schwarzschild metric in the usual spherical coords can be written in this form, just by replacing each term of the form $A\,dx_\mu^2$ with $\sigma_\mu^2$ using $\sigma_\mu=\sqrt{A}\,dx_\mu$.