# Special relativity in orbit

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, orbital-motion, time-dilation

I am writing something for school where I need to calculate the time dilation difference between Earth and Mars. First I calculated the difference from the gravity of the planets itself + that of the sun on the planets. I got 1.73 seconds in 10 years (so 1,73s slower on earth than on mars). A professor checked it for me and it is correct.
Now, this is only when the planets don't move because I haven't calculated the speed difference of the planets with it. Can I calculate the time dilation by the speed of the planets with the formula:
dt' = dt/(sqrt(1-v^2/c^2))
for the planets separate, then calculate the difference and adding that result to the 1.73? I am not sure because they move in an orbit but then the orbit is made by gravity (curving spacetime) and I already calculated that. I think that you can also do it in one step by not removing the spacecoördinates from the schwarzschild metric but I don't understand that entirely so it would be harder. So I am not sure if this is correct, can anyone help with this one?
Thanks!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110669/123208

Comment: To combine time dilations you should multiply them, because they are rates. However, if $a$ & $b$ are both close to zero, then $$(1+a)(1+b)\approx(1+a+b)$$ because the $ab$ term is even closer to zero.

Comment: I suppose that you're treating the orbits as circular. It's much trickier handling elliptical orbits, because the distances and orbital speeds vary. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJioV.png

Comment: you should be able to use the viral theorem to scale your answer with some clever looking at the forms of the dilations in terms of energy differences. Maybe.